# How to add WeakValueDictionary with callback functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, weak-references

How to pass call_back function to these dictionary ? so if any object get garbage collected will call that function .

```
import weakref

def call_back():
    print("call back function called")

we_dict_demo = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
```

or

```
we_dict_demo = weakref.WeakValDictionary()
```

Comment: You can put something in `__del__`, but there's no guarantee that it will be called.

Comment: thanks heemayl 
but I required similar kind of functionality like this which use for single object.
        **r = weakref.ref(obj, callback)**

but in case of dictionary , object may be used as key or value. Whenever object get deleted by garbage collector  it should called each time call_back()

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has practical meaning, but it is fun to try:

```
import weakref

def callback(elem):
    print(elem, "gc'ed!")


# After reading lib/weakref.py it's clear what 
# WeakKeyDictionary pushes as callback self._remove, 
# which constructed in __init__, so let's redefine it
class MyWeakKeyDict(weakref.WeakKeyDictionary):
    def __init__(self, cb, dict=None):
        super().__init__(dict)
        self.cb = cb

        def new_remove(el, selfref=weakref.ref(self)):
            self = selfref()
            if self is not None:
                self.cb(el)
                self._old_remove(el)

        self._old_remove = self._remove
        self._remove = new_remove


class C:
    pass

c = C()
#d = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
# Use our class instead of WeakKeyDictionary
d = MyWeakKeyDict(callback)

d[c] = 0

print('Before gc', list(d.items()))
del c
print('After gc', list(d.items()))
```

Result is

```
Before gc [(<__main__.C object at 0x000002690F53A588>, 0)]
<weakref at 0x000002690F54A728; dead> gc'ed!
After gc []
```